# Feh vertical flip all images in slideshow

Tags: linux, images, feh, image-viewer

I have a large dataset of images in a directory that I would like to view. `feh -f` works perfectly to quickly step through the images. The problem is that all the images are flipped upside down. While I could beforehand flip all the images, with for example the command tool `convert`, I'd much rather use an option where I flip the images just when viewing, and leave the dataset unedited.

I could start feh as I normally do and flip the images with the _ key. But this change will not stay when stepping to the next picture. Hence, this option makes it quite cumbersome when looking at a larger number of images.

My question is if there's a way to apply the above option, but to all images in a feh slideshow, or have a config setting where every picture that loads will flip vertically. What I would like is there to be a flag where I can execute feh and specify that all images should be flipped. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to bind a key command to a custom action command that will execute for every image loaded in a slideshow.

On a side note, I find it a bit surprising that there exist several key commands that don't have an equal flag option in feh. For example, I can't seem to find a flag option to even display just one image flipped vertically directly. I have to execute feh, then flip it using the underscore key.

I really feel like I'm missing something here.

Any ideas or feedback is hugely appreciated, thank you!